# Sentence Case SQL: RIGHT invalid Identifier

Tags: sql, vb.net, oracle10g, case-sensitive

I have tried to reference and use the follow examples that I have found:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3a170b84-a332-4553-bcc5-1e7a85bce8f1/display-data-first-letter-uppercase-rest-lowercase

http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/how-title-case-column-value

Like so:

**V1:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT upper(left(county,1))+lower(right(county,len(county)-1)) 
  as county     
  FROM tablename     
  order by county
```

**V2:**

```
UPDATE tablename
  SET county = UPPER(LEFT(county, 1)) + LOWER(RIGHT(county, LEN(county) - 1));
```

**to avoid:**

Having DISTINCT populate copies of text that are identical but are case sensitive [I have tested DISTINCT alone and it did in fact display the copies]

**What I want to do is:**

Display the text as sentence case for each distinct county value in database

**Issue:**

The issue I face is the fact that `RIGHT` gives me an error of **`Invalid identifier`**

**Is there a way to use my format but use a different value for `RIGHT`?**

Full chunk of VB.net coding to fill a dropdownlist:

```
If Not County_List Is Nothing Then

   Dim County As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT DISTINCT upper(left(county,1))+lower(right(county,len(county)-1)) as county FROM tablename order by county", conn)
   Dim OracleDataAdapterAds3 As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter
   OracleDataAdapterAds3.SelectCommand = County

   Dim DsAds3 As DataSet = New DataSet
   DsAds3.Clear()

      If Not (DsAds3 Is Nothing) Then
         OracleDataAdapterAds3.Fill(DsAds3, "tablename")
         County_List.DataSource = DsAds3
         County_List.DataMember = "tablename"
         County_List.DataBind()
         Dim newListItem As ListItem
         newListItem = New ListItem("", "")
         County_List.Items.Insert(0, newListItem)
         County_List.SelectedIndex = -1
     End If

End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using Oracle.  Oracle doesn't have `LEFT()` and `RIGHT()`.  Instead, use `SUBSTR()`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT upper(substr(county, 1, 1)) || lower(substr(county, 2)) as county     
FROM tablename     
ORDER BY county;
```

However, you might find `INITCAP()` (see [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions074.htm#SQLRF00650)) more to your liking:

```
select distinct initcap(county) as county
from tablename
order by county;
```

Comment: Yes I am using oracle but didn't realize RIGHT isn't supported by it. However, your -1 only shows 2 text of the string. how do I show them all? I can't put a specific number there since they vary in length

Comment: Thank you. `INITCAP()`  gave me the whole string. I will research about `INITCAP()` so I know what is happening behind the scenes

Comment: @narue1992 . . . My apologies.  When I see `len()`  used with `substring()`, my reaction is "get the last character".  It is now fixed.

Comment: Oh I see. your first statement now works. So instead of -1 it is 2.

Comment: Just realized you sent me a link over `INITCAP()`. Thank you!